# Expected type 'SupportsIndex', got 'float' instead

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

first time coding and 6th day. i am trying to compute compound interest given the code:

```py
p = float(input('Please input any amount\n'))
i = float(input('Enter the interest rate\n'))
no = float(input('''Enter number of times interest is compounded in a year eg per month = 12
            or per quarter = 4, and if per year, please enter 1\n'''))
t = float(input('Enter time period in years\n'))
qout = float((1 + (i/100))**t)
Qout = float((1 + (i/(100*no))**(t*no)))

Amount = []
if no >= 1:
    for x in range(0, t + 1):
        Amount.append(p*Qout)
    print(Amount)
else:
    Amount.append(p*qout)
print(Amount)
```

i get "Expected type 'SupportsIndex', got 'float' instead" on the for loop (t + 1) to be exact.
i want to iterate and get an amount at the end of each period other than giving me a sum for all years
on running the code,
the error

> Blockquote

```
for x in range(0, t + 1):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `t` should be an integer

Answer (score 0):

`t` shoud be an integer (the for loop needs an integer the way it is written).

```py
p = float(input('Please input any amount\n'))
i = float(input('Enter the interest rate\n'))
no = float(input('''Enter number of times interest is compounded in a year eg per month = 12
            or per quarter = 4, and if per year, please enter 1\n'''))
t = int(input('Enter time period in years\n'))  # <--- integer
qout = float((1 + (i/100))**t)
Qout = float((1 + (i/(100*no))**(t*no)))

Amount = []
if no >= 1:
    for x in range(0, t + 1):
        Amount.append(p*Qout)
    print(Amount)
else:
    Amount.append(p*qout)
print(Amount)
```